# if P=NP, and if language A is not NP-hard, A = ∅ or A = Σ*

Tags: np-hard, np

I don't know how to solve this.
Show that if P=NP, and if language A is not NP-hard, A = ∅ or A = Σ*

Comment: Don't change the question after it has been answered to an entirely different one.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$. You can show that the contrapositive statement is true: If $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq \Sigma^*$ then $A$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

Consider any language in $B \in \mathsf{NP}$. We will provide a poly-time computable function such that $x \in B \iff f(x) \in A$, thus showing $B \le_p A$. This will immediately imply that $A$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

Let $y \in A \neq \emptyset$ and $n \in \Sigma^* \setminus A  \neq \emptyset$.
Given $x \in \Sigma^*$, use the fact that $B \in \mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{P}$ to decide, in polynomial time, whether $x \in B$. If that's the case let $f(x) = y$. Otherwise, let $f(x) = n$.